# What can modify epfd to produce errno = EINVAL?

Tags: c, epoll

I have a program that reads from a list of domain name ip pairs and sends a http GET request and then `recv`'s the response. Everything works fine for thousands of queries and then the program loops infinitely doing nothing. Some debugging and I found that `epfd` had been turned into value `1` thus producing a `EINVAL` value of `errno`. My code is below but it will be difficult to reproduce if you don't have the requisite file of thousands of domain name ip pairs. So my general question is "What can modify `epfd`?"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PORT 80
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS 1024
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 1024
#define TIMEOUT 10000
int sockfd[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
struct epoll_event event[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
int epfd;
struct sockaddr_in dest[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
char servers[MAX_CONNECTIONS][128];
char domains[MAX_CONNECTIONS][128];
char get_buffer[MAX_CONNECTIONS][1024];
int buffer_used[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
                
void close_socket (int socket)
{
    close(sockfd[socket]);
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, sockfd[socket], &event[socket]);
}

void make_socket_and_connect (int sock)
{
    if ( (sockfd[sock] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }
    event[sock].events = EPOLLIN; // Cann append "|EPOLLOUT" for write events as well
    event[sock].data.fd = sockfd[sock];
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[sock], &event[sock]);
    bzero(&dest[sock], sizeof(dest[sock]));
    dest[sock].sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest[sock].sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[sock], &dest[sock].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
        printf("\n");
        perror(servers[sock]);
        exit(errno);
    }
    if ( connect(sockfd[sock], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[sock], sizeof(dest[sock])) != 0 ) {
        if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            printf("%s\n", servers[sock]);
            perror("Connect again ");
            //exit(errno);
            //close_socket(sock);
            //make_socket_and_connect(sock);
        }
        buffer_used[sock] = 0;
    }
}

int is_valid_ip(char *domain)
{
    if (!strcmp(domain, "255.255.255.255"))
        return 0;
    if (!strcmp(domain, "192.168.1.0"))
        return 0;
    if (!strcmp(domain, "127.0.0.0"))
        return 0;
        
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE * fp;
    char buffer[MAX_CONNECTIONS][MAXBUF];
    struct epoll_event events[MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS];
    int i, num_ready, connections = 0, done = 0, sent = 0, total_bytes = 0;
    struct timespec startTime, stopTime;
    
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &(struct sigaction){SIG_IGN}, NULL);
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /*---Open socket for streaming---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    { 
        if ( (sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
            perror("Socket");
            exit(errno);
        }
    }

    /*---Add socket to epoll---*/
    epfd = epoll_create1(0);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        event[i].events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT; 
        event[i].data.fd = sockfd[i];
        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[i], &event[i]);
    }

    /*---Initialize server address/port struct---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", domains[i]) == 1)
        {}
        else
           break;
        if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[i]) == 1)
        {
            //printf("Adding ip %s\n", servers[i]);
            bzero(&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i]));
            dest[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
            dest[i].sin_port = htons(PORT);
            if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[i], &dest[i].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
                perror(servers[i]);
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    

    /*---Connect to server---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if ( connect(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i])) != 0 ) {
            if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
                perror("Connect ");
                exit(errno);
            }
            buffer_used[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startTime);
    while (1)
    {
    
        /*---Wait for socket connect to complete---*/
        num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, TIMEOUT/*timeout*/);
        //printf("Number ready %d\n", num_ready);
        if (!num_ready) break;
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                //printf("Socket %d connected\n", events[i].data.fd);
                connections++;
                printf("%d\r", connections);
                
            }
        }
        /*---Wait for data---*/
        num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, TIMEOUT/*timeout*/);
        if (!num_ready) break;
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) {
                sprintf(get_buffer[events[i].data.fd], "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", "/", domains[events[i].data.fd]);
                //printf("%s", get_buffer);
                ssize_t nByte;
                //printf("%d %d %s\n", buffer_used[events[i].data.fd], strlen(get_buffer[events[i].data.fd]), get_buffer[events[i].data.fd] + buffer_used[events[i].data.fd]);
                if (buffer_used[events[i].data.fd] < strlen(get_buffer[events[i].data.fd]))
                    nByte = send(sockfd[events[i].data.fd], get_buffer[events[i].data.fd] + buffer_used[events[i].data.fd], 
                                 strlen(get_buffer[events[i].data.fd]) - buffer_used[events[i].data.fd], 0);
                sent++;
                //printf("%d\n", sent);
                if (nByte > 0)
                {
                    buffer_used[events[i].data.fd] += nByte;
                    total_bytes += nByte;
                }
                if (nByte == -1 && errno == EPIPE)
                {
get_domain_name2:
                    close_socket(events[i].data.fd);
                    if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", domains[events[i].data.fd]) == 1)
                {}       
                    else
                        done = 1;
        
                    if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[events[i].data.fd]) == 1)
                    {
                        if (is_valid_ip(servers[events[i].data.fd]))
                            make_socket_and_connect(events[i].data.fd);
                        else
                            goto get_domain_name2;                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        done = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stopTime);
            uint64_t msElapsed = (stopTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec) / 1000000 + (stopTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec) * 1000;
            double seconds = (double)msElapsed / 1000.0;
            fprintf(stderr, "total connections=%d elapsed=%2.2fs Mbit/s=%2.2f\r"
                    , connections, seconds, 8*total_bytes/seconds/1024/1204);
        }
        
        num_ready = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, TIMEOUT/*timeout*/);
        if (!num_ready) break;
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                bzero(buffer[events[i].data.fd], MAXBUF);
                ssize_t nByte = recv(sockfd[events[i].data.fd], buffer[events[i].data.fd], sizeof(buffer[i]), 0);
                if (nByte > 0) printf("Received: %s from %s at %s \n", buffer[events[i].data.fd], domains[events[i].data.fd], servers[events[i].data.fd]);
                total_bytes += nByte;
                if (nByte == 0)
                {
                    close_socket(events[i].data.fd);
                    if (!done)
                    {
get_domain_name:
                        if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", domains[events[i].data.fd]) == 1)
                {}       
                        else
                           done = 1;
        
                        if (fscanf(fp, "%127s", servers[events[i].data.fd]) == 1)
                        {
                            if (is_valid_ip(servers[events[i].data.fd]))
                                make_socket_and_connect(events[i].data.fd);
                            else
                                goto get_domain_name;                
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            done = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stopTime);
            uint64_t msElapsed = (stopTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec) / 1000000 + (stopTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec) * 1000;
            double seconds = (double)msElapsed / 1000.0;
            fprintf(stderr, "total connections=%d elapsed=%2.2fs Mbit/s=%2.2f\r"
                    , connections, seconds, 8*total_bytes/seconds/1024/1204);
        }
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stopTime);
        uint64_t msElapsed = (stopTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec) / 1000000 + (stopTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec) * 1000;
        double seconds = (double)msElapsed / 1000.0;
        fprintf(stderr, "total connections=%d elapsed=%2.2fs Mbit/s=%2.2f outer loop num_ready %d epfd %d MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS %d\r"
                , connections, seconds, 8*total_bytes/seconds/1024/1204, num_ready, epfd, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS);
        //if (num_ready == -1){
        //    if (errno == EINVAL) printf("%d %d\n", epfd, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS);
        //}
 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        close(sockfd[i]);
    }
    printf("Finished without errors\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output from the program

```
total connections=60023 elapsed=6.52s Mbit/s=1.41 outer loop num_ready -1 epfd 1 MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS 1024
```

Any ideas what is modifying `epfd` to make it `1` and produce `errno = EINVAL`?

EDIT

Running with ASan gives the following output:

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow /home/yaakov/epoll_recv.c:166 in main
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0ac6027d4e90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4ea0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4eb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4ec0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4ed0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0ac6027d4ee0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f9[f9]f9 f9 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4ef0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4f00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4f10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4f20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0ac6027d4f30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==6862==ABORTING
```

Comment: Have you attempted to run this program with the assistance of a sanitizer such as ASan or MSan to tease out any subtle out of bounds errors? If we can't actually run this program without the large input file, then we're likely reduced to guessing at your effective memory layout.

Comment: Perhaps you have memory corruption bugs somewhere. Try running in a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to check for memory issues. Or use a data breakpoint on `epfd` to try and catch when it is modified.

Comment: @kaylum valgrind points to this line: ```if (nByte > 0) printf("Received: %s from %s at %s \n", buffer[events[i].data.fd], domains[events[i].data.fd], servers[events[i].data.fd]);``` It says ```Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6421==    at 0x4849C68: strlen (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6421==    by 0x48E7E67: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1647)
==6421==    by 0x48D156E: printf (printf.c:33)
==6421==    by 0x10A561: main (epoll_recv.c:211)```

Comment: Well it is telling you that `nByte` may be used without being set. Which is clearly true from your code as the code that sets `nByte` is conditional but the code immediately after that which uses `nByte` is not. Also, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70559263/edit) the question to include such updated rather than put it in comments where it is difficult to read.

Comment: @kaylum I commented out the offending line and ran again. ```epfd``` still gets changed to produce ```errno = EINVAL```. Whatever the problem is with that line it is unrelated to the ```epfd``` problem.

Comment: @nanofarad I've edited the question to show ASan output.

Comment: Did you run valgrind again after commenting out those lines? There could be more bugs. Also, you probably don't need to post all the debugging output immediately. We are just pointing you to tools and techniques that may help you. You should spend some time learning and using those tools on your code to try and debug the issue further.

Comment: @kaylum Yes. I ran valgrind again. And it returned without any errors.

Comment: I feel like using libcurl's multi API would be easier than manually sending http requests...

Comment: The ASan output implicates line 166, but without line numbers it's not clear what that line is (and copy/pasting into my own text editor is risky in case of subtle line break/spacing differences between stack overflow's rendering and your original source file). Given that a buffer is overflowed, it's *plausible* but not certain that you may have overwritten epfd there.

Comment: @nanofarad Yeah. That seems to be what happened. I moved epfd initialisation to another place and the variable doesn't get overwritten anymore. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @nanofarad The offending line of code was ```if (buffer_used[events[i].data.fd] < strlen(get_buffer[events[i].data.fd]))```. I have no idea how this is a buffer overflow. It just compares to values. No assignments.